# Access VBA Multivalue

Tags: vba, ms-access

I know that it's not popular and people don't like it but i want try add MVF via form into table.

However for some reason it's not working.

is there any chance can help with the code to have optin add MVF into table

`

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TblTop")
rs.AddNew

rs![Capital City] = Me.CapitalCity
rs!Salary = Me.Salary
rs![MVF] = Me.MVF

rs.Update
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Recordset2:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset2
```

as `Me.MVF` is a recordset by itself.

But, as you've already seen, these MVFs will cause you nothing but trouble. The feature is aimed at non-programming users coming from Excel.